# Running a self-contained ASP.NET Core application on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, asp.net-core

I've published an ASP.NET Core application as a self-contained application targeting Ubuntu. The publish seems to work fine. I've copied the files to a pretty vanilla Ubuntu machine. Now, how do I run my application?

My understanding is that because it is a self-contained .NET Core application I *do not* need to download and install .NET Core anything. My application should contain everything it needs.

All tutorials seem to say I should call `dotnet run`. However, the "dotnet" command line doesn't exist (is it supposed to be published into the self-contained folder??) So if I call it, I get "command not found". Of course I could download .NET Core, but doesn't that go against the whole self-contained concept?

Here is a sample of the files I'm copying over:

[image]

Comment: I have no Idea as i'm not a dotnet dev, but I think you might need to install the dotnet cli on Ubuntu first. Is this something you need? https://github.com/dotnet/cli

Comment: I would agree with your assessment except it seems like one of the main points of publishing the application in a "self-contained" fashion is not to need to download anything else. The dotnet cli MIGHT be an exception to that but I don't think so.

Comment: I use a lot of "self contained" docker containers, without the docker service they don't run ;)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

## Answer

> Now, how do I run my application? My understanding is that because it is a self-contained .NET Core application I *do not* need to download and install .NET Core anything. My application should contain everything it needs.

You are correct. Run the executable.

When you create a self-contained app, the publish output "contains the complete set of files (both your app files and all .NET Core files) needed to launch your app." That includes the executable.

## Example Self-Contained Deployment

Here is the output of `dotnet publish -c release -r ubuntu.14.04-x64` for a simple self-contained application. Copy the publish directory to Ubuntu and run the executable.

C:\MyApp\bin\release\netcoreapp1.0\ubuntu.14.04-x64\publish\

```
...

libsos.so
libsosplugin.so
libuv.so
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.dll
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.dll
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.dll
Microsoft.CSharp.dll
Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
Microsoft.Win32.Primitives.dll
Microsoft.Win32.Registry.dll
mscorlib.dll
mscorlib.ni.dll
MyApp                        <------- On Ubuntu, run this executable
MyApp.deps.json                       and you will see Hello World!
MyApp.dll
MyApp.pdb
MyApp.runtimeconfig.json
sosdocsunix.txt
System.AppContext.dll
System.Buffers.dll
System.Collections.Concurrent.dll
System.Collections.dll

...
```

C:\MyApp\project.json

```
{
  "buildOptions": {
    "debugType": "portable",
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },
  "dependencies": {},
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": "1.0.1"
      }
    }
  },
  "runtimes": {
    "ubuntu.14.04-x64" : {},
    "win10-x64" : {}
  }
}
```

C:\MyApp\Program.cs

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

## See Also

[This document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/deploying/index) differentiates between framework-dependent and self-contained deployments.

Comment: I suppose up there the "MyApp" is actually "MyApp.exe" with file extension .exe?

Comment: @JP_medevice The `*.exe` extension is a Windows convention that does not apply to Linux. See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/156392/what-is-the-equivalent-of-an-exe-file

Comment: For ubuntu ignorants life myself: To run the executable you type .\ExecutableName on the terminal.

@ShaunLuttin maybe you could include this in your answer.

Comment: Running as described just results in a `command not found` error.... How do you actually run the self-contained publish output on linux?

Comment: Actually you use a forward slash to specify a relative path to an executable, not a backwards slash. So it's `./ExecutableName` on the terminal

Comment: @DouglasGaskell The answer has it all except for the Linux command to turn the "MyApp" file into an executable file by executing (inside the published folder): `chmod a+x ./MyApp`. Once completed you should be able to run the application by typing `./MyApp` followed by the Enter/Return key. (`./` means "from current directory/folder")

Answer (score 36):

Follow the below steps to run your application:

1. Publish your application as a self contained application:

   ```
    dotnet publish -c release -r ubuntu.16.04-x64 --self-contained
   ```
2. Copy the `publish` folder to the Ubuntu machine
3. Open the Ubuntu machine terminal (CLI) and go to the project directory
4. Provide execute permissions:

   ```bash
   chmod +x ./appname
   ```
5. Execute the application

   ```
    ./appname
   ```

**Author:** Harit Kumar

**Original answer here:** *[How to run a .NET Core console application on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46843863/how-to-run-a-net-core-console-application-on-linux/46861681#46861681)*

Comment: Execute permission is the key!

Comment: thank you so much, you saved me!! I was trying to run my app, but all the time got error that command not found, 4 step really did that thing!

Answer (score 9):

It's worth noting that with the [.NET Standard 2](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/versions/netstandard2.0.md)+, there are **two** required steps:

- Edit the .csproj file and add a line with a list of target runtimes:

> <PropertyGroup>
>
> ```
> <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
> <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
>
> <!-- Add this with the required runtimes -->
> <RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x64;osx.10.11-x64;ubuntu.16.10-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
> ```
>
> </PropertyGroup>

- Restore and build the app: `dotnet restore && dotnet build -c release -r RUNTIME`

Where RUNTIME is one of the runtimes listed in the .csproj file.

Importantly note that you cannot do this without the .csproj file edit and calling `dotnet restore`, or the runtime will not be downloaded from [NuGet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NuGet), and the `-r ...` flag will not work.

Answer (score 6):

You may want to check out [dotnet-packaging](https://github.com/qmfrederik/dotnet-packaging) as well. It includes a `dotnet deb` command line utility which allows you to create a `.deb` file (i.e. a Ubuntu installer) which you can use to install your app on Ubuntu. It should make deployment easier for you.

To get started, you'll first need to add this section to your `.csproj` file:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Packaging.Targets" Version="0.1.45" />
  <DotNetCliToolReference Include="dotnet-deb" Version="0.1.45" />
<ItemGroup>
```

Then, run `dotnet restore` and `dotnet deb -c Release -r ubuntu.18.04-x64 -f netcoreapp2.0`. This will create a `.deb` file you can use to deploy your application to Ubuntu.