# Creating standalone console application for Ubuntu.16.10-x64

Tags: .net-core, ubuntu-16.04

I'm attempting to create a standalone executable using dotnet core that will run on Ubuntu 16.10.  I've created a simple console application using

dotnet new console

I've then edited the .csproj to include Ubuntu as a RunTimeIdentifier:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>ubuntu.16.10-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Finally, I do the following to build and publish the app:
   1) dotnet restore
   2) dotnet build
   3) dotnet publish -c Release -r Ubuntu.16.10-x64

I then copy the resulting files to my Ubuntu Linux machine, and when I try to execute the app (./SimpleConsole), I get the following:

Error: assembly specified in the dependencies manifest was not found -- package: 'microsoft.codeanalysis.common', version: '1.3.0', path: 'lib/netstandard1.3/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.dll'

Comment: what are your package references?

Comment: Are you sure your linux machine is 16.10 and not 16.04? Also are you copying bin/Release/netcoreapp1.1/ubuntu.16.10-x64/publish/**

Comment: Thanks for the response, TerribleDev.  I don't have any package references, the above is my entire .csproj file.  I'm certain that I'm running on 16.10, and yes, I'm copying the entire publish directory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running Self-contained ASP .NET core application on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40226032/running-self-contained-asp-net-core-application-on-ubuntu)