# How to run a .NET Core console application on Linux

Tags: c#, .net-core, ubuntu-16.04

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and created a .NET Core console application. After compiling, I have my project DLL file in the *debug* folder. And if I want to run it on another computer, I have to install .NET on it and then write `dotnet myApp.dll` in command window (CMD). But I need to run my application without any installations.

I have read that I must publish my application. I do it with the command `dotnet publish -c Release`. Now in folder *release* I have a new folder, *publish*, with myApp.dll and other dll-files and folder runtimes for different systems. For example, in the *Ubuntu.16.04-x64* folder I have file *System.Security.Cryptography.Native.OpenSsl.so*. But how can I run my application without any new installations of .NET or something else?

Comment: You need dotnet installed for the commands you need to be available.

Comment: Is there any opportunity to make autonomous executable file (for example for windows)?

Comment: And If I setup dotnet on linux, how to run my app? I have only dll-files

Comment: I think you should be able to do that with Mono.

Comment: Ok, thank you)) I'll try.

Answer (score 194, accepted):

Follow the below steps to run your application:

1. Publish your application as a self contained application:

   ```
   dotnet publish -c release -r ubuntu.16.04-x64 --self-contained
   ```
2. Copy the `publish` folder to the Ubuntu machine
3. Open the Ubuntu machine terminal (CLI) and go to the project directory
4. Provide execute permissions:

   ```
   chmod 777 ./appname
   ```
5. Execute the application

   ```
   ./appname
   ```

Comment: |   CrossPlatformInstaller.deps.json
|   CrossPlatformInstaller.dll
|   CrossPlatformInstaller.pdb
|   CrossPlatformInstaller.runtimeconfig.dev.json
|   CrossPlatformInstaller.runtimeconfig.json
|   tree.txt
|   
\---publish
    |   CrossPlatformInstaller.deps.json
    |   CrossPlatformInstaller.dll
    |   CrossPlatformInstaller.pdb
    |   CrossPlatformInstaller.runtimeconfig.json
    |   System.AppContext.dll
    |   ...
    |   
    \---runtimes
        \---ubuntu.16.04-x64
            \---native
                    System.Security.Cryptography.Native.OpenSsl.so

Comment: that's my result folder with publish folder. Which folder I must copy to ubuntu machine? and which file I must run on ubuntu?

Comment: I can't execute dll-files on ubuntu

Comment: As i said above copy publish folder and you'll find CrossPlatformInstaller file inside that publish folder. You're checking files inside ubuntu.16.04-x64 which is not right. CrossPlatformInstaller (without extension) file is inside publish folder.

Comment: You can use this way also: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46264808/net-core-2-0-error-running-console-app-on-ubuntu?rq=1)

Comment: Should I install dotnet on ubuntu?

Comment: No need to install .NET Core on Ubuntu for self contained applications. Just follow the above steps.

Comment: I think, I don't understand something. I have publish folder with files: myApp.dll, myApp.pdb, myApp.deps.json, myApp.runtimeconfig.json. I copy this folder to ubunty. Then provide execute permissions: chmod 777 ./myApp.dll. Then try to execute it but can't ./myApp.dll

Comment: [Another link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40226032/running-self-contained-asp-net-core-application-on-ubuntu?rq=1)

Comment: What's inside your publish folder? If you can't find CrossPlatformInstaller file inside publish folder then application is not published properly. You've missed something.

Comment: I don't have exec file, I have only dll (((

Comment: I have publish folder with files: myApp.dll, myApp.pdb, myApp.deps.json, myApp.runtimeconfig.json.

Comment: Make sure you've specified <RuntimeIdentifiers>ubuntu.16.04-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers> also inside .csproj file PropertyGroup.

Comment: I'am using 2015 VS, and I have .xproj file. After additing RuntimeIdentifiers executable file didn't apear((

Comment: I install VS 2017 and now I have all these files))

Comment: @HaritKumar I have followed your process but it is not working. It will not generate .deb file. Give me some way to generate .Deb File

Comment: Thanks for sharing solution. Its working fine on my linux server but could you tell me how to schedule this ./appname on linux server like task scheduler. I want to execute this console app every 15 minutes after 5 PM every day.

Comment: How to execute the app not being in the apps folder??? "./appfolder/app" not working.

Comment: Are executable names converted to lowercase when deployed on Linux? If my project output is set to `MyProgram.exe` on Windows, does it appear as `myprogram` on Linux automatically?

Comment: One should just chmod to the least needed permission. 777 allows anyone to read and write and execute to the file, I wouldn't recommend it...

Comment: I could easily be wrong, but my reading (and experiments) suggests none of this works for a 'console' application, but only for a 'core' application.   For a console app it appears one needs to use mono instead.  Possibly vs 2017 allowed it, with vs2019 it seems impossible.  By all means correct me if I"m wrong :-)

Comment: @ChrisPugmire, knowing that it's a console app is not enough to know the framework.  A .NET Framework console app would require something like Mono as you suggest. The OP specifically asks about a .NET Core console app which does not require Mono.