# Installer for .NET Core project

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have developed a .NET Core console app. This app is not only targeted for Windows, but also for Linux.

What installer can I use to install the app to Linux? Preferably, I want a setup solution that handles both Windows and Linux.
I want some kind of installer because the app is intended for an offline Linux computer.

Off course, I know how to install it on Windows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running Self-contained ASP .NET core application on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40226032/running-self-contained-asp-net-core-application-on-ubuntu)

Comment: I think this question is too broad. DEB, RPM, apt repository etc etc. [Self-contained/Framework dependent deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/) (and therefore installation of dependencies)? There are just too many things to cover.

Comment: Just to clarify, dotnet 2.1 is supported on Red Hat, CentOS, Oracle Linux, Fedora, Debian, Ubuntu, Linux Mint, openSUSE, SUSE Enterprise Linux and Alpine Linux. There are many different ways of installing on these different platforms (let's not forget the dependencies too) and each one might require a different approach if you want an "idiomatic" installer.

Comment: To clarify: this app will be build by a buildagent for the desired platforms and an OFFLINE installer must be created. Why? because, believe it or not, in my case the Linux computers are offline. new versions are installed by inserting an USB stick and we want to run some kind of installer.

Comment: @spender in response to your second comment: that is exactly why I ask this! So if you could please answer the question, or otherwise undo the hold!

Comment: Who is voting to re-open this question? Asking for tool recommendations has always been off-topic.

Comment: unfortunately, none of the topic-closers has answered this problem. eventually I found it out myself. No thanks to beforementioned people. It involves creating an install script that first installs .net core to the target Linux platform, installing .net Core and then 'pushes'  the app to the target system. It is described in this post (I could publish it here, but  it is closed).. : https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2016/10/05/part-2-install-net-core-and-powershell-on-linux-using-dsc/

Comment: Glad you made headway with it.

Answer (score 2):

This is quite a broad question, but here goes.

In principle, installing a console app would likely mean pushing files around and maybe setting some values in a config file - operations that are trivial to accomplish from Powershell.

Given Powershell is now cross-platform, and you have chosen .NET Core for your console app, it could be a good choice for you as you'd only have one installer script codebase to maintain.