# ASP .NET CORE 2.0 - Unable to start service on Debian

Tags: c#, unix, .net-core, debian, systemd

I have a problem with .Net Core ConsoleApp. I am trying to run it on DebianOS 9.0 as daemon. As far I did:
1. Create app in Visual Studio.
2. Publish app from Visual Studio fox x64-linux
3. Copy code to DebianOS
4. Create service in /etc/systemd/system/newservice.service

Code of my service looks like:

```
[Unit]
Description=Test
DefaultDependencies=no

[Service]
ExecStart=/var/SystemdExample/ConsoleApp.dll
WorkingDirectory=/var/SystemdExample
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
User=netuser
SyslogIdentifier=ConsoleAppEx
Group=netuser

[Install]
WantedBy=multi.user.target
```

When i try to run it with `systemctl start newservice.service`
The return of this command is something like:

```
'newservice.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC'
```

Nothing else. Someone have idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot run the DDL directly, you have to call it as parameter of `dotnet`

Something like this :

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/path/to/your/app/hellomvc.dll
```

Comment: Thanks, work like a charm. What about if i have Self-Contained application not Framework-Dependent?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40226032/running-self-contained-asp-net-core-application-on-ubuntu

Comment: Ok, but doesn't explain me how to run it as a service. As far as I know the only difference is that i should remove `/usr/bin/dotnet` from ExecStart and it should run? I want to start service on boot of system, so I add it to `/etc/init.d/` and i have the same **Exec/203**

Comment: The service is the same as the one you created, just remove the /path/to/dotnet, and replace the .dll by the generated executable.

Answer (score 0):

For me:
status=203/EXEC indicating the execution is not running correctly.
Please check the path/location of the dotnet when you was installing, because it may not be in /usr/bin/dotnet.
Double check the location of your dll as well.

Do something like below:

```
ExecStart=/root/dotnet6/dotnet /root/YourAppFolder/YourAppName.dll
```