# .Net core application cannot run on Linux?

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core

I created a .Net core C# console application in Visual Studio and used the following steps to test it on Linux.

1. Use Visual Studio "Build -> Publish" menu item to create the executable files in `....\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\publish`.
2. Copy the "publish" directory to the Linux machine
3. On Linux, `chmod 777 myApp.dll`
4. `./myApp.dll`

However, executing the app shows the error of

> -bash: ./myApp.dll: cannot execute binary file

Comment: on Linux as well as on Windows, dynamic link libraries are not stand-alone executables. you could possibly only start executables (exe, extensionless in Linux by default) from a command line.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40230574/1132334

Comment: Does the Linux machine have the .NET Core runtime or SDK installed?

Comment: Yes, I read the SO question too. I thought it would generate an executable file `myApp` for Linux by Visual Studio but it didn't.

Comment: @RQDQ, no it doesn't. I want to create a self-contained .Net net core application.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like you did a [Framework-Dependendent Deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/#framework-dependent-deployments-fdd). Essentially, the publish command was:

```
dotnet publish -c Release
```

FDD assumes that you are going to have a .NET Core runtime to run your application on the target platform.

Once you copied over the `publish` directory to another machine (which could be Linux, macOS or Windows), your application still needs a .NET Core runtime to run your application.

Installing the .NET Core runtime depends on the particular Linux distribution that you are using. Once you have it installed, you can run your application by doing:

```
dotnet /path/to/publish/myApp.dll
```

An alternative to Framework Dependent Deployment is [Self-Contained Deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/deploy-with-vs#simpleSelf). In this mode, the published application will contain your application as well as a copy of the .NET Core runtime. On command line, doing a a SCD publish looks like this:

```
dotnet publish -r linux-x64 -c Release
```

For doing this in Visual Studio, see the link above. Then, you should see a `bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\linux-x64\publish\` directory that contains a `myApp` file. You can copy over this publish dir over to a Linux distribution and just run:

```
/path/to/linux-x64/publish/myApp
```

Comment: I tried `dotnet publish -r linux-x64 -c Release` and it got `Error:
  An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (myApp.deps.json) was not found:
    package: 'AWSSDK.Core', version: '3.3.24.8'
    path: 'lib/netstandard1.3/AWSSDK.Core.dll'`

Comment: I donwnloaded `awssdk.core.3.3.24.8.nupkg` and it contains `lib/netstandard1.3/AWSSDK.Core.dll`. Does the package exist on your disk? Does it contain this file?

Comment: I was in the wrong directory. It works when running the same `myApp` under the directory of `Publish`. However, I will need to manually copy the file `appsettings.json` from parent folder. It sounds like a glitch of .Net core publish.