# Fail to run C# console app (net 6.0) on Linux

Tags: c#, mono, debian, .net-6.0

I have a C# console app written under net 6.0. And I ran it complied exe file (I complied it in Windows and upload whole published folder to Linux VM) using mono, and get following message:

file does not contain a valid CIL image.

I checked the other thread and re-install dotnet package. But it still does not work out.

Please provide some help. Thanks.

Comment: Why not compile directly for linux? See [this for an example to target Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41533671/6621862)

Comment: How did you compile it? You can't run Windows exe on Linux.

Comment: .NET Framework-style exe's can be run in Linux with Mono, because they contain the .NET program code. However, starting with .NET 5 -- or even perhaps already starting with .NET Core -- the exe file typically (albeit depending on the project's publishing settings) does not contain the .NET program code anymore. Rather, projects are built into an exe with _native_ code only plus a separate DLL with the actual .NET code. So, instead of trying to run the exe, try to run the DLL that's accompanying the exe...

Comment: Did you download the runtime version of core for linux : https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the answer:

1. Mono is not compatible with .net 6 so far.
2. The correct command line to run the code is:

dotnet program.dll

(exe file is not working here)

Thanks for you guys' help.

Answer (score 0):

.NET 6 is not compatible with Mono, so if you want your .NET 6 console app to run on Linux, you should need to strictly follow the .NET Core/.NET 6 guides,

[Running a self-contained ASP.NET Core application on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40226032/running-a-self-contained-asp-net-core-application-on-ubuntu)

The "complied exe file" generated for a .NET 6 console app by `dotnet publish`, is strictly a native Windows executable (equivalent of .NET CLI executable) that contains no MSIL. That's why when you force Mono runtime to load it "file does not contain a valid CIL image" is reported. Don't check any other threads, as Mono is going away and not what you should resort to at this moment, https://halfblood.pro/the-end-of-mono/