# asp.net core 3.1 self-contained single file + linux-x64, ubuntu 20.04 can't run app

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, ubuntu

I read [Running a self-contained ASP.NET Core application on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40226032/running-a-self-contained-asp-net-core-application-on-ubuntu)
and publish setting like below

[image]

published file
[image]

and upload to ubuntu without dotnet sdk/runtime, and command `app_name` but ubuntu show `app_name: command not found`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and upload to ubuntu without dotnet sdk/runtime, and command app_name
> but ubuntu show app_name: command not found

It means that `dotnet` command has not been recognized by `Ubuntu 22.04 (LTS)`. In this scenario please `Install the SDK` `(which includes the runtime)` if you want to develop `.NET apps` Or, if you only need to run apps, `install the Runtime`.

*If you're installing the Runtime, Microsoft's suggestion is to install the ASP.NET Core Runtime as it includes both .NET and ASP.NET Core runtimes. You can see [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu)*

**How would you check whether install succeeded:**

You can see which versions of the `.NET SDK` are currently installed with a terminal. Open a terminal and run the following command.

`dotnet --list-sdks`  *To check SDK Version List*

`dotnet --list-runtimes` *To check DotNet Runtime Version*

`dotnet --version` *To check Lastest Installed Version*

If you still encounter `command not found` means your installation didn't get succeeded. For more details please check our [`official document here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/how-to-detect-installed-versions?pivots=os-windows)